# Type is not callable for openZeppelin function

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol"; 


contract SharedWallet is Ownable {
    
    mapping(address => uint) public allowance;
    
    modifier ownerOrAllowed(uint _amount) {
        require(onlyOwner() || allowance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "You are not allowed");
        _;
    }
    
    function addAllowance(address _who, uint _amount) public ownerOrAllowed(_amount) {
        allowance[_who] = _amount;
    }
    
    function withdrawMoney(address payable _to, uint _amount) public onlyOwner{
        _to.transfer(_amount);
    }
    
    receive() external payable {

    }
}
```

Hello I'm getting a error when I try to deploy this contract it's saying the type is not callable and is pointing at the onlyOwner() inside the modifier. I'm using openZeppelin and it has a modifier called onlyOwner() so this should work? I been trying to find the problem but can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call a [modifier](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/contracts.html#function-modifiers) (in your case `onlyOwner()`) as a function.

You can do a workaround by copying the [onlyOwner](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L42) contents and using them in your `ownerOrAllowed`.

```
// replace `onlyOwner()` call to its contents: `owner() == _msgSender()`

modifier ownerOrAllowed(uint _amount) {
    require(owner() == _msgSender() || allowance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "You are not allowed");
    _;
}
```